# discord.py "command is already existing alias" error, but it isnt

Tags: python, discord.py

I recently decided to learn how to use discord.py commands, and I've been having a little bit of trouble adding a command. No matter what I change my command to, it always gives the same error when I try to add it:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: The command hellothisisacommand is already an existing command or alias.
```

Trouble is, it obviously isn't, and no matter what I change my command to, it always gives this error. What could be causing this? Code is below.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True
client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@bot.command()
async def hellothisisacommand(ctx):
    await print(True)
    
bot.add_command(hellothisisacommand)
client.run('token')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `bot.command()` decorator is essentially equivalent to (and precludes the use of) `bot.add_command`.

You can either use the `commands.command()` decorator and then call `bot.add_command`, or you can use the `bot.command()` decorator, but not both.

[Read the docs for more info](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html)

Here's the example from the docs:

> There are two ways of registering a command. The first one is by using Bot.command() decorator, as seen in the example above. The second is using the command() decorator followed by Bot.add_command() on the instance.
>
> Essentially, these two are equivalent:
>
> ```
> from discord.ext import commands
>
> bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')
>
> @bot.command()
> async def test(ctx):
>     pass
>
> # or:
>
> @commands.command()
> async def test(ctx):
>     pass
>
> bot.add_command(test)
> ```